# Easy way to load test asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, performance, scalability, load-testing

Is there a simple way to load test an asp.net application? I've been reading on some microsoft pattern and practices documents that tell you to use ACT which seems kind of hard to use for complex requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will note that the documentation that refers to ACT is dated about 2004.

Visual Studio Ultimate allows you to load test a website with up to 250 virtual users, which is enough for most load testing needs. Beyond that licences for the "Visual Studio Load Test Virtual User Pack 2010" [breath] are available.

[Ed Glas's blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/edglas/) on the load testing tool contains much in depth information, but the "guidance" tag brings up posts that link to getting started information.